# How to get sum of nested JSON elements in Long format using scala and play?

Tags: json, scala

I have nested JSON like -

```
"disks" : [ {
        "name" : "v2.16",
        "diskAggregate" : "aggr0",
        "diskRPM" : 15000,
        "totalSizeBytes" : 1077477376,
        "vendorId" : "NETAPP  ",
        "usedBytes" : 1070071808,
        "diskType" : "FCAL",
        "uuid" : "4E455441:50502020:56442D31:3030304D:422D465A:2D353230:32353836:30303030:00000000:00000000",
        "portName" : "FC:A ",
        "raidGroup" : "rg0"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "v4.16",
        "diskAggregate" : "aggr0",
        "diskRPM" : 15000,
        "totalSizeBytes" : 1077477376,
        "vendorId" : "NETAPP  ",
        "usedBytes" : 1070071808,
        "diskType" : "FCAL",
        "uuid" : "4E455441:50502020:56442D31:3030304D:422D465A:2D353230:32353633:34333030:00000000:00000000",
        "portName" : "FC:B ",
        "raidGroup" : "rg0"
    }]
```

I want to get addition 'totalSizeBytes' from above list of objects.

I used following code to get it -

```
val storageDevices = "above given json".toList   
val totalCapacity = storageDevices.foldLeft(0) {
    case (sumOfAllDevices, storageDevice) =>
      val sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice = storageDevice.disks.foldLeft(0) {
        case (totalBytesOnDevice, disk) =>
          totalBytesOnDevice + disk.usedBytes.getOrElse(0).toString.toInt
      }
      sumOfAllDevices + sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice
    // Logger.info("dss"+sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice.toString.toInt)
  }
```

This code gives me total capacity in Integer format. But as there are too many objects in disks array, the totalCapacity will get exceed int. So I wanted to convert it to Long while doing addition.

I want following output-

```
"totalCapacity": [
  {
    "name": "192.168.20.22",
    "y": 123456789
  }
]
```

How do I convert it to Long to get exact sum of all 'totalBytesAvailable' from array/list???

Answer (score 1):

Cast zero values as `0L` (by default assumed `Int`), both in `foldLeft(0L)` and in `getOrElse(0L)`, so the compiler will enforce arithmetic additions on `Long`.